# AWS changed the way a service works. What is the right way to handle questions about this in certification exams?

Tags: amazon-web-services

example:
Previously we could attach an IAM role to an EC2 instance only at launch time. Now, EC2 service allows you to attach an IAM role to an existing instance

Answer (score 1):

The AWS Certification Exams have a policy of only referencing new services after they have been available for at least 6 months. This not only give students a chance to learn new features/services, but also allows time for exam revisions.

Updating exams can take a lot of time because new questions need to be written, reviewed, tested on a sample of students, then released.

In situations where a question becomes invalid, questions would be removed quickly once it is realised that a situation has changed and a question is no longer valid.

It is also unlikely that there would be a question on such a minor detail as the one you mention in your question. An exam might test your understanding of how IAM Roles can be assigned to an instance as a way of passing credentials to an application, but it is unlikely to test a minor detail such as the fact that it could (previously) only be assigned at initial launch.

Comment: @HakanBayraktar - I have taken 9 AWS certification exams. My advice is to answer the question based upon the current feature sets. AWS is free to change the answers at anytime so trying to guess which time frame is not a good idea. Also, John's answer is correct based upon my experience.